# Как настроить работу скрипта?

Tags: jquery, three.js

Использую Distortion Hover Effect для анимации изображений. Как настроить переключение анимации при hover на элемент "trigger"?

Мой пример https://codepen.io/spacek8989/pen/poveVGa

Оригинальная анимация `https://tympanus.net/Development/DistortionHoverEffect/#`

Comment: А с чем возникли трудности?

Comment: неужели чтобы сменить картинку нужно писать такую кучу кода? или тут какой-то спецэффект должен был быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если подобной эффект будет работать только для одного блока на странице, то можно статически прописать параметры в hover.js:

```
var parent2 = document.querySelector('.trigger');
```

Будет выглядеть так:

```
var parent = opts.parent || console.warn("no parent");
var parent2 = document.querySelector('.trigger'); // НОВАЯ ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ
var dispImage = opts.displacementImage || console.warn("displacement image missing");
.......
```

В блоках:

```
parent.addEventListener(evtIn, function(e) {
            TweenMax.to(mat.uniforms.dispFactor, speedIn, {
                value: 1,
                ease: easing
            });
});

parent.addEventListener(evtOut, function(e) {
            TweenMax.to(mat.uniforms.dispFactor, speedOut, {
                value: 0,
                ease: easing
            });
});
```

parent меняем на parent2

```
parent2.addEventListener(evtIn, function(e) {
            TweenMax.to(mat.uniforms.dispFactor, speedIn, {
                value: 1,
                ease: easing
            });
});

parent2.addEventListener(evtOut, function(e) {
            TweenMax.to(mat.uniforms.dispFactor, speedOut, {
                value: 0,
                ease: easing
            });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! А что делать, если несколько таких конструкций? Пробую использовать массивы, но постоянно появляются ошибки https://codepen.io/spacek8989/pen/gObRaJB

Answer (score 0):

Для нескольких блоков.
1) Html будет выглядеть так:

```
<div class="ticket">
        <div class="trigger">Trigger</div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="flight-info">
        <h3>JUNE 30 2018 12:30PM</h3>
        <div class="flight-locations">
          <h1>LAX</h1>
          <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*QFU_XYAKOGJ9nunfqvem1w.png" />
          <h1>JFK</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ticket">
        <div class="trigger">Trigger</div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="flight-info">
        <h3>JUNE 30 2018 12:30PM</h3>
        <div class="flight-locations">
          <h1>LAX</h1>
          <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*QFU_XYAKOGJ9nunfqvem1w.png" />
          <h1>JFK</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Блок "trigger" перенесен внутрь родителя "ticket"

2) Вызов функции будет след.:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ticket')).forEach((el) => {
                //const imgs = Array.from(el.querySelectorAll('img'));
                new hoverEffect({
                    parent: el,
                    parent2: el.querySelector('.trigger'),
                    intensity: el.dataset.intensity || undefined,
                    speedIn: el.dataset.speedin || undefined,
                    speedOut: el.dataset.speedout || undefined,
                    easing: el.dataset.easing || undefined,
                    hover: el.dataset.hover || undefined,
                    image1: 'https://source.unsplash.com/Le7_qK9JaLU/1600x900',
                    image2: 'https://source.unsplash.com/XAqaeyzj3NM/1600x900',
                    displacementImage: el.dataset.displacement
                });

            });
```

С помощью массива обращаемся к каждому блоку отдельно.
Добавляем "parent2: el.querySelector('.trigger')", наш новый элемент

3) В hover.js вносим изменения:

```
var parent2 = opts.parent2 || console.warn("no parent2");
```

Будет выглядеть так:

```
var parent = opts.parent || console.warn("no parent");
    var parent2 = opts.parent2 || console.warn("no parent2");
    var dispImage = opts.displacementImage || console.warn("displacement image missing");
    ....
```

Ну и опять таки меняем блок прослушки с parent на parent2
Было:

```
parent.addEventListener(evtIn, function(e) {
            TweenMax.to(mat.uniforms.dispFactor, speedIn, {
                value: 1,
                ease: easing
            });
});

parent.addEventListener(evtOut, function(e) {
            TweenMax.to(mat.uniforms.dispFactor, speedOut, {
                value: 0,
                ease: easing
            });
});
```

Стало

```
parent2.addEventListener(evtIn, function(e) {
            TweenMax.to(mat.uniforms.dispFactor, speedIn, {
                value: 1,
                ease: easing
            });
});

parent2.addEventListener(evtOut, function(e) {
            TweenMax.to(mat.uniforms.dispFactor, speedOut, {
                value: 0,
                ease: easing
            });
});
```